# How can I permanently display the current playback position in SMPlayer?

Tags: smplayer

I can display information on the current playback position by hovering with the mouse. However, can I also permanently display this information without having to do a mouse over?

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options > Toolbars > Edit control bar

At the end of "Available actions:" there is the option "Current time (current_timelabel_action)". Select it, add to "Current actions:" and click "OK".

Answer (score 0):

Just for amendment, in `Mini GUI` mode, there is no `current time` or `total time` in `available actions`. Instead you should select `display time`.